Using a list (range) of row and column critiera (not single cells) in SUMPRODUCT formula



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




1

initial
tested
2023
2024
2025

Row Criteria


2
Brand A
70
yes
500
70
60

initial


3
Brand A
45
yes
100
47
300

2024


4
Brand A
20
yes
800
21
200




5
Brand B
30
yes
90
56
150




6
Brand C
56
no
45
700
790




7
Brand C
84
no
600
150
40

Result


8
Brand D
70
yes
900
90
980




9
Brand D
34
yes
125
854
726




10
Brand D
125
yes
70
860
614




11
Brand D
14
yes
842
250
85




12
Brand E
64
no
300
324
450






I want to filter the table based on multiple row and column criteria. 
The row criteria you can find in range H2:H3 
The column criteria you can find in range I2:I3 
As you can see in the screenshot - in this example - the result in Cell I7 is:
=(70+45+20+30)+(70+47+21+56) = 359


I tried something like this:
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(IF(H2="",1,(B1:F1=H2))*IF(H3="",1,(B1:F1=H3))*IF(I2="",1,(A2:A12=I2))*IF(I3="",1,(A2:A12=I3))*(B2:F12),0))

but it gives me 0 as result.

Is there some kind of solution to include the entire range of row and column criteria into the SUMPRODUCT formula. 
Something like this:
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(IF(H2:H3="";1;(B1:F1=H2:H3))*IF(H2:H3="";1;(B1:F1=H2:H3))*IF(I2:I3="";1;(A2:A12=I2:I3))*IF(I2:I3="";1;(A2:A12=I2:I3))*(B2:F12);0))

or do you have any other idea how to solve this issue?

Idea is to use COUNTIF as FILTER criteria for multiple values:
=SUM(FILTER(FILTER(A2:F12,COUNTIF(H2:H3,A1:F1)),COUNTIF(I2:I3,A2:A12)))


Just keep in mind that you need to look for headers IN criteria range and not vice versa:

Using just COUNTIF and multiplication:
=SUM(IFERROR(COUNTIF(I2:I3,A2:A12)*COUNTIF(H2:H3,B1:F1)*B2:F12,0))



=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(H2:H3,B1:F1)*COUNTIF(I2:I3,A2:A12),B2:F12)) might just do. Nice solution!

A slight variation on this where I've tried to put in the idea from the previous question that blanks should work like wild cards:
=SUM(((COUNTIF(H2:H3,B1:F1)+COUNTBLANK(H2:H3))>0)*
((COUNTIF(I2:I3,A2:A12)+COUNTBLANK(I2:I3))>0)*N(+B2:F12))




Using COUNTIF(array, criteria) instead of COUNTIF(criteria, array) will let us use wildcard and other conditions for criteria (for example: >2022 )
Also, for convenience and maintenance we could setup tables for the filters: row_filter  & col_filter.

Then we could use the following for the sum:
=LET(
_data, data,
_cols_to_filter, DROP(TAKE(_data,1),,1),
_rows_to_filter, TAKE(_data,,1),
_filter_array, LAMBDA(array,criteria, MAP(array,LAMBDA(el,OR(COUNTIF(el,criteria))))),
_include_col, HSTACK(TRUE, _filter_array(_cols_to_filter, col_filter)),
_include_row, _filter_array(_rows_to_filter, row_filter),
IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(FILTER(_data,_include_col),_include_row)),
"No results for: " & TEXTJOIN(" / ",,row_filter,col_filter))
)

Sample result:


